# Why is my ident not reseeding

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to reseed the PK field in some tables I imported.
The columns are defined correctly as Identity Specification = Yes.

I've run the following command.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('tableName', NORESEED)
```

and get the following reply:

> Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL', current
>   column value '42'. DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error
>   messages, contact your system administrator.

I then run the following:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('tableName', RESEED, 42)
```

and get this reply:

> Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL'. DBCC
>   execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your
>   system administrator.

I then run the original comand to see if the table was reseeded:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('tableName', NORESEED)
```

And the reply is:

> Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL', current
>   column value '42'. DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error
>   messages, contact your system administrator.

Why has the table not reseeded? Running commands as DBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... what I've done to get around this is whenever I get the `current identity value as 'NULL'`, I run this command

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('tableName', RESEED, 0)
```

I then run:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('tableName', NORESEED)
```

and the response is:

> Checking identity information: current identity value 0, current
>   column value '42'. DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error
>   messages, contact your system administrator.

I then run:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('tableName', RESEED, 42)
DBCC CHECKIDENT('tableName', NORESEED)
```

And I then get the correct response:

> Checking identity information: current identity value 42, current
>   column value '42'. DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error
>   messages, contact your system administrator.